# How to make expressions with hours in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like a way to add or subtract hours in flutter. For example, if I add 1.30 + 0.30 the result should be 2. How can I do this?

Comment: you can create check  two condition for this , also if it is text, try to parse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using `Duration` class

```
Duration duration1 = Duration(hours: 1, minutes: 30);
Duration duration2 = Duration(minutes: 30);
Duration totalDuration = duration1 + duration2;

int totalHours = totalDuration.inHours; // get the total hours as an integer
print(totalHours); // prints 2
```